# How to connect with Impala with Kedro?

Tags: kedro

How to connect with Impala with Kedro? Is there any integration with it? I am using a Window machine.
I try Impyla and ibis and both doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the [Pandas](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.extras.datasets.pandas.SQLQueryDataSet.html) or [Spark](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.extras.datasets.spark.SparkJDBCDataSet.html) JDBC `DataSet` types.

Comment: pandas.read_sql seems relies on sqlalchemy, and from what I read, it doesn't integrate with impala. So I am not sure how I can use the Kedro datacatalog for impala query.